# How to instrument correct handling of null source values, when target is custom container (i.e. not List, Map, Optional)?

Tags: java, mapstruct

We use MapStruct 1.5.3 for class mapping between several layers. One layer has 'simple' properties (i.e. int, Integer, BigDecimal, String), the other container properties, where the containers has additional metadata:

```
@ lombok.Data
class SimpleClass {
    String name;
    String title;
    [...]
}
```

```
@ lombok.Data
class ContaineredClass {
    StringContainer name;
    StringContainer title;
    [...]
}

@ lombok.Data
class StringCountainer extends Container<String>{
     String value;
     int allowedMaxLength;
     boolean mandatory;
     [...]
}
```

For the class mapping we are using the "update" variant:

```
void mapSimpletoContainer(SimpleClass simple, @MappingTarget ContaineredClass containered);
```

We do have special "update" functions which are used to update the inner value inside the container, so updating works, even if the source value is NULL (in that case, the inner value is cleared as intended):

```
class persistenceUtils {
      public void update(String value, @MappingTarget StringContainer container) {
            container.setValue(value);
      }
}
```

Before mapping from SimpleClass to ContaineredClass, we initialise all the containers, esp. setting metadata.

For the mapper implementation, MapStruct renders a null check on the target container, but this is no problem, we make sure the target container will never be null.

Unfortunately, MapStruct also renders a null check on the *source* value before updating, and in case of source-NULL the whole container will be nulled:

```
public void mapSimpletoContainer(SimpleClass simple, ContaineredClass containered) {
      [...]
      if ( simple.getName() != null ) { // This IF is the problem
            if ( containered.getName() == null ) {
                containered.setName( new StringContainer() );
            }
            persistenceUtils.update( simple.getName(), containered.setName() );
      }
      else {
            containered.setName( null ); // This is the error
      }
      [...]
}
```

This NULL container causes fails.

How can one get rid of the outer IF-construct at all?
-OR-
How can one cause a special updating for the ELSE part?
-OR-
Where a better documentation for the @Condition configuration, esp. how to finetune its configuration for respecting when rendering of the Mapper implementation?

We tried NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE, this eliminates the else-branch of the outer if-construct, but this means, in case of NULL the container value will not be altered.

We don't want to add a @Condition for every property, as this is error prone: the set of properties will change over the life of the application.

We tried an appropriate global @Condition (which will always return true) but suffered problems to have it used in the Mapper implementation:

1. catch all

   ```
   @Condition
   default boolean always(Object value) { return true; }
   ```

   This catch-all-approach is too broad; it will be used for ALL mappings of the Mapper implementation (we define both directions in the same mapper and would like to keep it that way, but this would certainly be a workaround).
2. Narrow by source value class

   ```
   @Condition
   default boolean always(String value) { return true; }
   ```

   This is too specific and would needed to be repeated for all "simple" types; but also a workaround.
3. Using @Mapping target

   ```
   @Condition
   default boolean always(Object value, @MappingTarget ContaineredClass containered) {
         return true;
   }
   ```

   This would be preferable, but somehow will not be picked/applied when rendering the Mapper implementation.